# cairo.so missing from R base package grDevices in linux centos

Tags: r, linux, svg, centos, cairo

Recently installed R 3.2.4 on CentOS and when trying to create png charts through R, I am getting the following warning:

> Warning in (function (filename = if (onefile) "Rplots.svg" else "Rplot%03d.svg",  :
>     unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so':
>     /usr/local/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   Warning in (function (filename = if (onefile) "Rplots.svg" else "Rplot%03d.svg",  :
>     failed to load cairo DLL

From searching online, it seems X11 is needed for cairo to work correctly, but even after installing that I am still getting the warning. Also tried installing the Cairo package from R and that didn't work either.

I checked the libs folder under grDevices and confirm there is no cairo.so.

As I understand this was supposed to be included in the installation of R but I am not seeing it. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got almost same warn message after installing R 3.5.0 in Ubuntu 14.04 with *source* and evaluated `rmakrdown::render`.

I also did not have `cairo.so` and got errors.

after I reinstalled with `--with-cario`

```
./configure --with-cairo --with-x && \
make && \
sudo make install
```

now I have `cairo.so`.